# Select Root Domain (Home Page) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add some conditional logic to check if a user is on the "Home Page".  However, it seems I need to add an absolute URL to make it work, which I don't want to do.

Here is what I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (window.location.href == "/") {
      console.log("this is home");
    }

    else {
      console.log("this is not the home page");
    }
}
```

I have also tried `top.location.href`with no luck.  When I look at both `window.location.href` and `top.location.href` in console I get the full URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Location object has other properties than just `href`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: @CBroe.  I am aware of that, but the href is what I am trying to target. So how can I target the page that I need?

Comment: _“but the href is what I am trying to target”_ - no, it is not. You want to compare the _path component_ of the URL only. And if you check the document I referred to, you would see that there is a property that contains just that explicitly.